# SQL search about exclude

Tags: sql

I can not figure out one problem about the SQL search from one table which has columns (name, population, area), which is below:

"Show the countries that are big by area or big by population but not both. Show name, population and area."

My command is below:

```
SELECT name, population, area from world
WHERE population > 250000000 OR area > 3000000
EXCEPT 
SELECT name, population, area from world
WHERE population > 250000000 AND area > 3000000
```

But it says You have an error in your SQL syntax. Anyone can offer me some hint about this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Which database are you using? MySQL? SQL Server?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It is the latter one. SQL Server.

Comment: For SQL server, that should be valid SQL. Could you please add the actual (complete) error message and SQL server version to the question?

Comment: I concurr, this is valid T-SQL. Please post any other SQL in the same batch. Also, how are you executing it? If you're in SQL Server Management Studio make sure you don't have any text selected in the editor when you click Execute.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The complete error message is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXCEPT 
 SELECT name, population, area from world
 WHERE population > 250000000 ' at line 3

Comment: @HuanianZhang MariaDB (which the error indicates you're running) is not SQL Server, it's a fork/version of MySQL. MariaDB does not support the `EXCEPT` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally wouldn't bother with the except. You can get what you need in one where clause.

```
SELECT name, population, area from world
WHERE (population > 250000000 and area < 3000000) --big by population but not area
OR (population < 250000000 and area > 3000000) --big by area but not population
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. But I wonder why the exclude command does not work.

Comment: Ahha, it's because you're using MariaDB, not sql server. The original syntax you posted would work exactly the same way as my query in sql server.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. I am just doing some Interactive SQL Tutorial for job preparation. It says "Learn SQL using: SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, DB2, and PostgreSQL.", so I thought it is SQL Server. Thanks. Why different database types have such difference?

Comment: There is a common standard for the SQL language itself, but each 'rdbms' - like SQL Server/ MySQL/ ... has a slightly different implementation. Basic query syntax is very very similar across all platforms. It's the more complex stuff, or the rarer keywords (like except) where you start to see differences.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.